# How to change language in Game Center Leaderboards/Achievements

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I've made a game that use GameKit (leaderboards and achievements) where the user is able to change game language by tapping on a flag. My trouble now are how I can change the language in the standard GameKit's view.

I've tried to achieve this by using:

```c
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAccessibilityLanguage:@"en-EN"];
```

and

```c
GKAchievementViewController* achievementsVC = [[[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[achievementsVC setAccessibilityLanguage:@"en-EN"];
```

but this don't do the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be following properly localization approaches, your app and game kit should follow the language settings that are set at a device level, not at an app level. You cannot force game kit into another language, the user needs to change their language in the settings.app.

Comment: Then I can only change the application language (because I create label's and other stuffs) but I'm not able to setup for example the NSError description and iAP descriptions in a custom language?

Comment: Both of those items are localizable, NSError has a property to get the localizedDescription and you localize iAP descriptions directly in iTunes Connect

Comment: Yes, but inside my application I can't specify wich language use because iOS automatically get the device language. For example if I am italian the application automatically get the italian localization for achievements and errors. And for a developer is impossibile to force iOS to use a custom language (different from the device language)... it's this true?